# Add role to the customer and give certain permissions in Magento

Tags: magento, permissions, addition, product

I am working on the website where by using magento I need to create an account when the user is registered, then I need to give that user permission to add products to my predefined categories. I don't know how this could be done. And I really need help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for a dropshipping extension.
This one is said to be one of the best: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magento-vendor-dropshipping-extension.html
There are few of these types of extensions, so a quick google search will show you all of them.

Answer (score 0):

are you referring to a customer on the front-end or an admin user on the back-end?

For an admin user you can limit a admin users permissions by assigning them to a role that can only interact with the catalog module.

Comment: I am referring the customer from the front end but I need to extend the idea of the standard magento customer and give him permission to add products. Is that possibel somehow?

Comment: I would say that anything is possible, but I would also say that if you plan to implement something like this you are in for a lot of work.